# Сертификаты SSL. Закрытый ключ

Tags: ssl, openssl, сертификат

Есть 2 отдельных файла с расширением (.cer). Оба не содержат закрытый ключ. Возможно ли такое, что один сертификат является закрытым ключом для второго? Просто их так сконвертировали. Если да, то как их слить в один сертификат (.pfx например) с помощью OpenSsl?

Или закрытый ключ явно должен быть формата (.key) или (.pem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сертификат - это сертификат. Ключ - это ключ. Сертификат не может быть ключом другого сертификата.

Comment: Спасибо! буду искать ключ от сертификата)